# Issue with calculating difference between two dates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to calculate difference between two days in minutes.

```
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

    NSString* dateStringFromDatabase = @"01/01/1900 11:00:00 AM";

    NSDate* dateFromString = [outputFormatter dateFromString:dateStringFromDatabase];

NSString* a = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSDate* b = [outputFormatter dateFromString:a];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:dateFromString
                                                  toDate:b options:0];

    int hours = [components hour];
    int minutes = [components minute];

    self.lblResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", hours, minutes];
```

But I have the following issues:
For current hours I get:

```
2012-10-21 07:37:09 +0000 // wrong it's two hours late
```

When I try to cast `@"01/01/1900 11:00:00 AM"` to `NSDate` I get

```
1900-01-01 10:00:00 +0000 // also two hours late
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `-dateStyle` rather than the time style, as there is also a date contained in that string.

Edit---

You now need to change the `-dateFormat` to `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a`

Comment: I don't understand? What should I do? Should I store dateTime in database in different format?

Answer (score 1):

Try This..................

if you have date in String then convert it into date using `@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"`

```
NSDate *startDate = ...;
NSDate *endDate = ...;
```

Now Date comparison

```
// Date Comparision
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:LastDate
                                              toDate:CuurentDate options:0];
```

Getting the difference between two dates

```
int months = [components month];
int days = [components day];
int hours = [components hour];
int minutes = [components minute];
```

Comment: I wan't to calculate difference between two NSDate, but only between hours. My first NSDate is 1900-01-01 10:00:00 +0000 and the second is 2012-10-20 15:50:53 +0000 when I try to get minutes between those I get 59328354.93... how to compare only time that is all I need?

Comment: Ok.....You have two dates. after that Start From "Date comparisson" part from above answer.......and mean while.....From int minutes = [components minute];
you will get diff between two date in minutes.....Try above code....it will do that

Comment: @Downvoter: if you downvote....please provide the reason.....i would like to know what's my mistake.....

Comment: @1110 : please use @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" NSDateFormatter.

Comment: @max_ : thanks.....didn't see that....i thought he will use the for-matter which i have told him to use in very beginning of my answer..

Comment: I have edited my question based on your answer I still have some issues can you please check edited question...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
    NSString *dtString = @"1900-01-01T11:00:00";
    dtString = [dtString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    NSDate *toTimeDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dtString];
    NSString *toTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:toTimeDate];
```